# How to create a project in Knockout3.1.0.js

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

I am making a project in JQM with the help of (cordova 3.2,knockout-3.1.0.js,jquery 1.9.1,jquery-mobile 1.3.2)

in which i m using ajax calling in "GET" method "POST" method.
Please help me out how to calling these two method.
I am new to knockoutjs i dont nw how to call ajax.
I gone too many documentation but i get confused,
and how to pass the value from one html page to another html page,
and if my json is in nested json ,

In "GET" method my data is coming in nested json how to append in li tags

a.js

```
        function AppViewModel() {

        this.username = ko.observable();
        this.password = ko.observable();

        this.loginvalidation = function() {
            var currentVal = this.username();
            var currentValue =  this.password();    
            var jsonvalue =  { UserId : currentVal, Password : currentValue};
            if((typeof currentVal == "undefined")||currentVal == "" && (typeof currentValue == "undefined")||currentValue == ""){
                alert("please enter username and password");
            }else if((typeof currentVal == "undefined")||currentVal == ""){
                alert("please enter username ");
            }else if((typeof currentValue == "undefined")||currentValue == ""){
                alert("please enter password");
            }else{
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "xyz url",
                    data: JSON.stringify(jsonvalue),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    processdata: false,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.mobile.changePage('#home', false);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

    $(document).on('pageinit','#index',function() {
        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
    });
```

Comment: take a look at [this](http://raheelshan.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/knockoutjs-make-parent-and-child-structure-in-your-app/).

Comment: I suggest you go through the tutorials at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/. They are really good and you'll probably get answers for a lot of questions which usually arise during learning knockout.